# Is there anyway to show SQLSTATE[HY000][1049] CUSTOM exception in laravel blade ?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've recently installed laravel, everything is working fine. All i'm trying to achieve is to show Custom db error messages or callback methods.
If i add/create database to sql server,it will work fine but i want to make it like wordpress installation.
If anyone can give me reference to some article that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` and override the method like below:

```
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if (method_exists($e, 'render') && $response = $e->render($request)) {
            return Router::toResponse($request, $response);
        } elseif ($e instanceof Responsable) {
            return $e->toResponse($request);
        }

        $e = $this->prepareException($e);

        if ($e instanceof HttpResponseException) {
            return $e->getResponse();
        } elseif ($e instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            return $this->unauthenticated($request, $e);
        } elseif ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
            return $this->convertValidationExceptionToResponse($e, $request);
        } elseif ($e instanceof QueryException){
            return $this->customQueryException($e, $request);
        }

        return $request->expectsJson()
        ? $this->prepareJsonResponse($request, $e)
        : $this->prepareResponse($request, $e);
}
```

And then add the custom message exception.

```
private function customQueryException(QueryException $e, $request){
   return response('Your custom message here');
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bother but it still reflecting same exception.

Comment: @ViperTecPro make sure you are using the correct exception class.

Comment: Wow amazing i just added this use Illuminate\Database\QueryException; and It worked. Thank you so much